# como transformo este algoritmo de pascal a c++

Tags: c++, array, estructuras-de-datos, pascal

Hola a todos soy estudiante de primer semestre de lic. en informatica y en mi universidad nos mandaron a aprendernos los lenguajes de manera autodidacta, hasta ahora hemos visto pascal pero nos ordenaron a que aprendiéramos c/c++, actualmente estamos trabajando con módulos y arreglos, mi problema es que he tenido grandes problemas al implementar esto ultimo aprendido a c/c++ a continuación voy a colocar un código con el que he tenido estas dificultades:

```
    program sumamatrices;
    const
       x =4;
    type
      tiparre= array [1..x,1..x] of integer;
    var
    a,b,c : tiparre;
    Fi,Co: integer;
    procedure limpiar (var a,b,c : tiparre);
    begin
      for Fi := 1 to x do
      begin
        for Co:= 1 to x do
            begin
                a[Fi,co]:= 0;
                b[Fi,co]:= 0;
                c[Fi,co]:= 0;
            end;
        end;
      end;
      procedure llenar (var a,b:tiparre);
      begin
        for Fi:= 1 to x do
          begin
             for Co:= 1 to x do
             begin
               writeln ('ingrese el valor de a en la posicion ',Fi,', ',Co);
               readln(a[Fi,Co]);
               writeln ('ingrese el valor de b en la posicion ',Fi,', ',Co);
               readln(b[Fi,Co]);
             end;
          end;
      end;
      procedure sumar (var a,b,c: tiparre);
      begin
        for Fi:= 1 to x do
        begin
          for Co:= 1 to x do
           begin
             c[Fi,Co]:= a[Fi,Co] + b[Fi,Co];
             writeln ('el valor de c en la posicion',Fi,',',Co,'es ', c[Fi,Co]);
           end;
        end;
      end;
      procedure determinar (a:tiparre);
      var
        cont: integer;
      begin
        cont:=0;
        for Co := 1 to x do
        begin
          if a[Fi,Co] = 1 then
            begin
              cont:= cont +1
            end;
        end;
        if (cont = x) then
          begin
            writeln('la diagonal de a es 1');
          end;
      end;
      begin
        limpiar (a,b,c);
        llenar (a,b);
        sumar (a,b,c);
        determinar(a);
      end.
```

si alguno de ustedes tiene los conocimiento y la disposición para realizarme el favor de traducirme este código estaría muy agradecido, realmente me ayudaría bastante a la comprensión de este lenguaje

Comment: Hola Victor, bienvenido a la familia de SOes, me agrada la forma que tuvo tu docente a mandarlos a aprender de manera autodidacta, pues es lo que se necesita en esta industria (claro que también hay ayudas mediante sitios como el presente). Te sugiero leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask para que próximamente puedas seguir redactando buenas pregunta. Aquí te comparto un tutorial de C++ http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/index.htm y en caso el idioma sea una limitación, puedes ir con Bing/Google Translate o aprender en www.memrise.com www.duolingo.com www.engvid.com salu2

Comment: El lenguaje `c/c++` no existe. En general deberás cambiar `begin` y `end` por `{` y `}`, traducir los bucles [`for`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) y [funciones](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function),  usar [`std::cout`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) en lugar de `writeln` y declarar variables al estilo C o C++. Ah, los `if` en C o C++ no tienen `then`.

Comment: muchas gracias por tus recomendaciones, me siento bastante alegre de estar en una comunidad tan solidaria como esta seguire tus consejos y vere el link gracias por todo

Answer (score 2):

Hola primero antes de todo el migrar un programa hecho en pascal a C++ no es tan complicado ya que los dos lenguajes comparten muchas características aunque no sintacticamente si en la forma de plantear y resolver problemas.

Te recomiendo ver este enlace:http://www.pp4s.co.uk/main/tu-c-intro.html para saber las equivalencias entre un lenguaje y otro lamentablemente el documento esta en ingles pero viendo los ejemplos te puedes guiar.

Con respecto a tu pregunta te hice una pequeña migración el cual intente de mantenerlo igual.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int LEN=4;
typedef int Array2DInteger[LEN][LEN];


void _clear(Array2DInteger a,Array2DInteger b,Array2DInteger c){

    for(int fi=0;fi<LEN;fi++){
        for(int co=0; co<LEN;co++){
            a[fi][co]=0;
            b[fi][co]=0;
            c[fi][co]=0;
        }
    }
}

void _fill(Array2DInteger a,Array2DInteger b){

    for(int fi=0;fi<LEN;fi++){
        for(int co=0;co<LEN;co++){
            cout<<"Ingrese el valor de a en la posicion "<<fi<<" "<<co<<endl;
            cin>>a[fi][co];
            cout<<"Ingrese el valor de b en la posicion "<<fi<<" "<<co<<endl;
            cin>>b[fi][co];
        }
    }
}

void _add(Array2DInteger a,Array2DInteger b, Array2DInteger c){
    for(int fi=0;fi<LEN;fi++){
        for(int co=0;co<LEN;co++){
            c[fi][co]=a[fi][co]+b[fi][co];
            cout<<"El valor de c en la posicion "<<fi<<" "<<co<<" es "<<c[fi][co]<<endl;
        }
    }
}

void _determine(Array2DInteger a){
 int counter=0;
 int fi=0;

    for(int co=0;co<LEN;co++){
        if(a[fi][co]==1)  counter++;
    }
    if(counter==LEN-1){
        cout<<"La diagonal de a es 1"<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Array2DInteger a,b,c;

    _clear(a,b,c);
    _fill(a,b);
    _add(a,b,c);
    _determine(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias por ayudarme tanto a  traducirlo como pasarme el link con las equivalencias, me siento feliz de estar en una comunidad como esta, espero en un futuro yo tambien poder ayudar a otros asi como lo has hecho tu

Comment: Los símbolos que empiezan por guión bajo (`_`) están desanconsejados en C++ (apartado 2.10.3 del estándar): Identificadores que contengan un doble guión bajo `__` o empiecen con un guión bajo y una letra mayúscula están reservados para cualquier uso. Identificadores que empiezan con guión bajo `_` están reservados para nombres en el espacio de nombres global.

Comment: Vale la pena mencionar que en Pascal los arreglos se indexan desde 1 mientras que en C y C++ se indexan desde 0.

Comment: por lo menos en mi casono coloco el ( _ ) el compilador me arroja un mensaje parecido a esto "type was not declared in this scope", si por causualidad mal entendi tu comentario por favor hasmelo saber

Comment: PaperBirdMaster  los arreglos se indexean como tu quieres no necesariamente desde 1 pueden quedar arreglos asi  "arreglo:array[2..10]of integer;" los unicos que siempre inician desde 1 son los strings y por ultimo los arreglos dinamicos inician desde 0.